# Prove that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, curves

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for every continuous curve, $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$: $f\circ\gamma$ is continuous. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

So I know we shall prove it by a contradiction. Let's assume that $f$ isn't continuous at $x_0$. Then, there's a sequence, $\{x_k\}$ converging to $x_0$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_k) \ne f(x_0)$.

Now, I need to have some curve in order to get a contradiction.

I'd be glad to get help with that.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to think that it is immediate that there exists such a sequence $x_k$. Is it?

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: The negation of continuity is not what you wrote. Continuity may also fail if the limit does not exist. After this (more complicated part) what is in the answers is the easy part.

Comment: @Jonas Continuity says for every sequence $\{x_k\}$ converging to $x_0$, $\lim f(x_k) = f(x_0)$. If continuity fails, there is a sequence for which $\lim f(x_k) \neq f(x_0)$. The negation of continuity is precisely what OP wrote. It is possible that the limit does not exist, but that doesn't contradict what OP wrote.

Comment: If you say so. :-)

Comment: @Jonas I guess you were referring to the missing "converging to $x_0$" bit. In which case, fair enough.

Comment: Read carefully my second comment above. Don't you really see it?

Comment: @Jonas My guess is that we're having terminology issues. By $\lim f(x_k) \neq f(x_0)$, I really mean $\{f(x_k)\}$ does not converge to $f(x_0)$, instead of saying it has a limit which is not $f(x_0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a curve "joining the points" $x_1$, $x_2$,... with $\gamma(0) = x_1$, $\gamma(1/2) = x_2$,...

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need a sequence $\{x_k\}$ of points converging to $x_0$.

Consider a piecewise-linear curve $\gamma : [0, 1] \to \Bbb R^n$ passing through $x_0$, joining $x_k$'s by straightlines.